# How can I implement parallel Cartesian Product efficiently using C++ Cuda

Tags: c++, cuda, cartesian-product

I have two arrays A and B which have m and n int variables respectively. I have a function f, and I want to generate all f(a, b) which a is in A and b is in B:

```
A = {a1, a2, a3, ...., am}
B = {b1, b2, b3, ...., bn}

C = f(A * B) = {f(a1,b1), f(a1,b2), f(a1,b3), ..., f(a1, bn),
                f(a2,b1), f(a2,b2), f(a1,b3), ..., f(a2, bn),
                ...
                f(am,b1), f(am,b2), f(am,b3), ..., f(am, bn)}
```

More precisely, my function f is a simple bitwise or between numbers, but I wanted to ask it in general. Moreover, the order of the items in the result is not important. I only want to generate all possible pairs from A and B.

As I need to generate and store the result, how can I implement it efficiently (using C++ Cuda) to reduce the number of visiting the global memory? Do I need to use shared memory?

Any recommendation will be really appreciated.

Comment: I think mathematically (except if A or B is a special series like `1..m`) you have to do m*n multiplications. You probably expected that.

Answer (score 5):

The idea is to operate on a thread blocks of size 32x32 for example. For each thread block at the location `(i, j)`, `a[i:i+32]` can be loaded in shared memory by a part of the threads in the current block. The same thing applies for `b[j:j+32]`. Then, all the threads can compute `f(shared_a[thread_i], shared_b[thread_j])` where `shared_a` and `shared_b` are the values previously loaded in the shared memory, and `thread_i` and `thread_j` are the index of the thread in the current block.

For better performance, a thread block can compute many close chunks of size 32x32. For example a thread block of 32x32 can compute 4x4 packed chunks of size 32x32 (resulting in 128x128 items). The idea is to load more values in the shared memory so that they are less reloaded.

That being said, node that writing the `C` matrix in memory will be very expensive and this will certainly make all the previous optimizations worthless. Computing the operation that require `C` on the fly should be a good idea.

Comment: If the memory operations are the bottleneck and output size is fixed, we can try to minimize the input size. We could load as many elements from `a` into shared memory as fit there. Then each of the 1024 threads within the block loads one element of `b` from global memory; in a loop it loads one element of `a` from shared memory, calculates a cell, writes to output. Repeat both loops. To cache even more elements from `a` we can use the registers for it, too - we have 256 KB to grab there, but have to cyclically exchange the data between the threads with shared memory and shuffle.

Comment: The returns of those optimizations are small, if A and B do not have totally dissimilar size (result is more rectangular than squared). But small optimizations could also be good.

Comment: @Sebastian Regarding your second comment, I should say that exactly you are right. If A and B have different sizes then we will have rectangular than squared. So, I think your answer would be more compatible with my project as usually A is much smaller than B in my project and I really need to store the entire C to use it in the next generation of numbers. But the order is not important.

Comment: While the proposed optimizations are good in general to speed up such code. I do not expect this to be faster here, since using shared memory for blocks should already be enough to *saturate* the GPU RAM bandwidth as long as `C` is written back in the main RAM. Doing the operation using less instruction does fix the *memory bandwidth* issue. That being said, the optimizations are interesting if `C` blocks can be computed *on-the-fly* in the kernel (so it can become compute-bound instead of memory-bound). This is what I meant in the last sentence of the answer.

Comment: The further gains achievable would be really minimal. If you assume a submatrix of 32x32 elements processed with shared memory. Per iteration you would store 1024 values and read 64 values from global memory. That is 6% overhead. Only those can be further reduced with the methods I mentioned. With registers I meant the max. 64K 4-byte registers per block or 1K per thread. They can store 256KB, but cannot be addressed with indexing. One has to be careful: If you overdo code generation to manually name the variables, the overfull instruction cache of a very long kernel can slow down the program.

Comment: Can you somehow combine two iteration steps? Even if it takes more calculations, the saved global memory accesses could be worth it. Or can the data be compressed? How large is the C array? The new Ada Lovelace GPUs will have up to 96MB of L2 cache. Could it hold C?

Comment: How often is each element in C read again? Are those used of C elements local (i.e. nearby elements are read for operations, which are also near to each other or share data)? If you read the 64 constituting values and calculate a C element on the fly instead of reading the result from memory, it would save the memory bandwidth twice.

Comment: @Sebastian In my Ph.D. project, I have a super big array named cache which has a few numbers initially, and A and B are actually two separate parts of that like A = cache[i:j] and B=cache[i':j']. I start with a small A and B, and they generate a small C (like my question here) and again after storing unique numbers of C into the cache, we will assign bigger A and B and again they generate a bigger C, and so on. So A, B, and C grow exponentially and they fill the super big array, cache.

Comment: @Sebastian Currently, due to the memory limitation in Google Colab, array C has about 500M uint64_t variables in it and I think I have no other choice as it is so big. Anyway, I think using shared memory cannot help us that much and I should get access to the global memory directly even for several times. As size(C) = size(A)*size(B), I call my kernel with size(C)/1024 blocks and each thread finds the right index in A and B to fill its index in C properly.

Comment: @Sebastian As you mentioned, in the best case, we need at least O(size(A)+size(B)) for reading and O(size(A)*size(B)) for writing. However, in my current implementation, for each writing, I am reading A and B, and it is much more than enough, however, I have no idea about using shared memory to reduce it.

Comment: In the worst case (as you currently implemented) for each output element you read twice and write once. So +200% overhead. But the L1 cache mitigates it. Please run with Nvidia Nsight Compute to see the cache efficiency.

Comment: For reading global memory into shared memory in the beginning of your kernel you would do (pseudocode): if(warpno == 0, same as thread==0..31) copy A into shared memory; if(warpno==1, same as thread==32..63)copy B into shared memory;__syncthreads();continue normally with calculation. Explanation: For 32x32 elements: 64 of your threads would do the copying, then there is a synchronization. Then all threads can do the processing and read A and B from the newly filled shared memory. When writing to global memory, let the threads in one warp write to memory locations, which are beside each other

Comment: If the elements of A and B are all over the place instead of directly following each other in memory (*coalesced*), the accesses to them are slower and they would waste memory bandwidth. Read up about coalescing (if you do not know already). Use Nsight Compute too see, what factors have an influence and can be optimized. Be considerate about how you map rows and columns to the memory layout of your 2D data structures and which memory addresses really succeed each other in 1D.